# Puppeteer Error: failed to find element matching selector "#save"

Tags: html, dom, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to click on the following button:

```html
<button 
  _ngcontent-fgf-c7="" 
   class="solo-button action-button mat-button mat-button-base mat-raised-button" 
   id="save" 
   mat-button="" 
   aria-label="Accept all vendors and purposes" 
   tabindex="0" 
   style="color: rgb(74, 73, 73); background-color: rgb(0, 255, 208);">     <span class="mat-button-wrapper">
    <div _ngcontent-fgf-c7="" class="action-wrapper" style="font-size: 14px;">
      <span _ngcontent-fgf-c7="">Alle akzeptieren</span>
    </div>
  </span>
  <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div>
  <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
</button>
```

with the following Puppeteer line:

```
await page.$eval('#save', form => form.click());
```

but I get the error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: failed to find element
> matching selector "#save"

I also noticed something interesting - when I open the website in an incognito window, I cant manually select the button with the Developer Tools. It seems "hidden"

Comment: What does "hidden" mean? Can you share a link to the site so we can see it?

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/berlin/berlin/friedrichshain-kreuzberg/wohnung-mieten?numberofrooms=2.0-&price=-900.0&pricetype=rentpermonth&enteredFrom=result_list

Comment: The popup with the desired button is in an iframe. Furthermore, the iframe belongs to a different domain (`https://gdpr-consent-tool.privacymanager.io/1/index.html#/notice`), so you can't reach it from JS, that's a cross-domain access that's forbidden by browsers. I think your best take on this is to try to figure out how else you can close the popup, e.g. setting some cookies.